# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\cos^2(n)\right)}n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\cos^2(n)\right)}n$ converge? 
I tried to use Dirichlet's theorem, but it doesn't work. So what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there's an easier proof for divergence not using equidistribution and density: $\cos^2n\in[0,1]$ and $\sin x$ is concave in that interval, so $\sin\cos^2n\ge\sin1\,\cos^2n$. So $\sum\sin\cos^2n\ge\sin1\left(\frac{1}{2}\sum\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\sum\frac{\cos2n}{n}\right)$. The first series is divergent, the second one convergent, the latter because of *Dirichlet's test* (the partial sums 0f $\cos2n$ are bounded).

Comment: it is $sin(cos^2(n))$ and not the product of $sin(n)$ by $cos^2(n)!!!$

Comment: @daniel11 $\sin(x)$ is concave over $[0,\pi]$. For $x \in [0,\pi]$,$\lambda \in (0,1)$,  we have
$$\sin(\lambda x) = \sin((1-\lambda)0 + \lambda x ) \ge (1-\lambda)\sin(0) + \lambda \sin(x) = \lambda\sin(x)$$
Now take $x = 1$ and $\lambda = \cos(n)^2$.

Answer (score 4):

I think the series diverges.

Let $P := \{n\in\mathbb{N}:\ \cos^2 n \geq 1/2\}$.
Since the sequence $(n\ \text{mod}\ 2\pi)$ is equidistributed in $[0,2\pi]$, the natural density of $P$ is positive.

Furthermore, since $\sin \cos^2 n > 0$ for every $n$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin \cos^2 n}{n}
\geq \sum_{n\in P} \frac{\sin \cos^2 n}{n}
\geq \left(\sin\frac{1}{2}\right) \sum_{n\in P} \frac{1}{n}\,,
$$
and the last series diverges to $+\infty$ since $P$ has positive natural density.

Comment: I repeat it is $sin(cos^2(n))$ and not the product

Comment: Where do you see such a product? For $n\in P$, (by definition of $P$) $\cos^2n\ge\frac{1}{2}$ and thus $\sin\cos^2n\ge\sin\frac{1}{2}$ due to the monotony of $\sin x$ in $[0,1]$.